# Ошибка WeasyPrint Python: OSError: no library called "cairo" was found

Tags: python, python-3.x

При запуске WeasyPrint в консоли возникает ошибка:

```
PS D:\PYpython> python -m weasyprint http://weasyprint.org weasyprint.pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\weasyprint\__init__.py", line 440, in <module>
    from .css import preprocess_stylesheet  # noqa isort:skip
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\weasyprint\css\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from . import computed_values, media_queries
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\weasyprint\css\computed_values.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .. import text
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\weasyprint\text.py", line 14, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    ('libcairo.so', 'libcairo.2.dylib', 'libcairo-2.dll'))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 45, in dlopen
    raise OSError(error_message)  # pragma: no cover
OSError: no library called "cairo" was found
cannot load library 'D:\Program files D\GTK3-Runtime Win64\bin\libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo.so': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e
```

Устанавливал всё по инструкции для Windows из [официальной документации](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).
Пытался исправить по [этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62868520), но не помогает.

Как можно исправить эту проблему?

Comment: Ошибка возникает в модуле `cairocffi`, попробовал по инструкции https://cairocffi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#importing и тоже ошибка "cannot load library", странная библиотека, пробовал с двумя установщиками gtk

Comment: Путь точно правильный `D:\Program files D\GTK3-Runtime Win64\bin\libcairo-2.dll`? Еще проблема может быть в битности dll и питона. Библиотека и питон должны быть одной битности -- 32 или 64

Comment: Путь правильный, питон и библиотека 64 бита

Comment: https://www.cairographics.org/download/ отсюда винарник ставить пробывали?